# Dynamic LINQ queries when two tables are joined

Tags: c#, linq

I want to dynamically build the where clause for a LINQ query but I am puzzled as how to go about and do this.

Here is the pseudo code that would not compile. Gives the error message

*Error  CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>'*

```
var tbl1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DBT_Master), "x");
var tbl2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DBT_MASTER_ADDRESS), "p");
var exp = Expression.And(Expression.Constant(true), Expression.Constant(true));

if (customerCode != "")
{
    exp = Expression.And(
        Expression.Constant(true), 
        Expression.Lambda<Func<DBT_Master, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(tbl1, "CustomerCode"),
                Expression.Constant(customerCode)
            ),
            tbl1
        )
    );
}
if (siteNo != "")
{
    exp = Expression.And(exp, 
            Expression.Lambda<Func<DBT_MASTER_ADDRESS, bool>>(
                Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.Property(tbl2, "AddressCode"),
                    Expression.Constant(siteNo)
                    ),
                tbl2
            )
        );
}

var results = (from x in db.DBT_Master
                join p in db.DBT_MASTER_ADDRESS on x.CustomerCode equals p.CustCode
                select x).Where(exp);
```

Comment: What is your expected where expression? Can you share it?

Comment: Essentially I am trying to construct 
When both customerCode and siteNo have values then:
    Where CustomerCode = customerCode and AddressCode = siteNo

if customerCode has a value and siteNo does not have a value then
    Where CustomerCode = customerCode

if siteNo has a value and customerCode does not have a value then
    Where AddressCode = siteNo

and lastly if both siteNo and customerCode do not have a value then
    Where (true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found a solution to your problem. I simulate it with IQueryable and it works well. You just need to replace list.AsQueryable() with your db.DBT_Master and list2 with db.DBT_MASTER_ADDRESS.

The working example is here :

```
class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<DBT_Master> list = new List<DBT_Master>();
            list.Add(new DBT_Master { CustomerCode = "test" });
            list.Add(new DBT_Master { CustomerCode= "test1" });
            list.Add(new DBT_Master { CustomerCode = "test12" });
            list.Add(new DBT_Master { CustomerCode = "test13" });

            List<DBT_MASTER_ADDRESS> list2 = new List<DBT_MASTER_ADDRESS>();
            list2.Add(new DBT_MASTER_ADDRESS { AddressCode = "1234", CustCode="test" });
            list2.Add(new DBT_MASTER_ADDRESS { AddressCode = "asdfs", CustCode = "test" });
            list2.Add(new DBT_MASTER_ADDRESS { AddressCode = "afsadfas" });
            list2.Add(new DBT_MASTER_ADDRESS { AddressCode = "fdsa" });

            var customerCode = "test";
            var siteNo = "1234";

            var query = (from x in list.AsQueryable()
                         join p in list2.AsQueryable() on x.CustomerCode equals p.CustCode
                         select new { DBT_Master = x, DBT_MASTER_ADDRESS = p });

            if (customerCode != "")
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.DBT_Master.CustomerCode == customerCode);
            }

            if (siteNo != "")
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.DBT_MASTER_ADDRESS.AddressCode == siteNo);
            }

        query.Select(x => x.DBT_Master).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
        }
    }

    class DBT_Master
    {
        public string CustomerCode { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return CustomerCode;
        }
    }

    class DBT_MASTER_ADDRESS {
        public string AddressCode { get; set; }
        public string CustCode { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return AddressCode + " " + CustCode;
        }
    }
```

When you run the program it prints "test" as result because there is only one data which matches the given conditions (customerCode = test and AddressCode=1234 and join on CustomerCode = CustCode)